# How to remove Cache data of NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad after 1 week of inactivity?

Tags: ios, nsurlcache

I am using `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` *cache policy* to speed up API call responses in my app. I want to remove specific cache data whose inactivity duration exceeds 1 week. Is there any mechanism to achieve this?